# UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animate:completion not delaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I've seen a few questions related to this here at SO, but none of them seem to quite answer this: the `delay` part of `UIView` `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animate:completion:` won't delay. Here is the actual code that calls it:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"about to start animateWithDuration...");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 delay:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                     animations:^{NSLog(@"in the animations block..."); self.textView.hidden = YES;}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){if (finished) {NSLog(@"In the completion block..."); self.textView.hidden = NO; [self.player play];}}];
}
```

And here is the `NSLog` timestamps:

> 2013-06-18 15:27:16.607 AppTest1[52083:c07] about to start animateWithDuration...
>
> 2013-06-18 15:27:16.608 AppTest1[52083:c07] in the animations block...
>
> 2013-06-18 15:27:16.609 AppTest1[52083:c07] In the completion block...

As one can see, the instructions are being performed milliseconds apart, and not 2 or 3 seconds delayed. Would anyone know the reason for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `hidden` property is not animatable:

> The following properties of the `UIView` class are animatable:
>
> > `@property frame`
> >
> > `@property bounds`
> >
> > `@property center`
> >
> > `@property transform`
> >
> > `@property alpha`
> >
> > `@property backgroundColor`
> >
> > `@property contentStretch`

Try using one of those properties in your animation block and then the delay should occur.  For example, you could animate the `alpha` from `1.0` to `0.0` and then hide it in the completion block.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I've also got the job done by not using animateWithDuration: at all, instead using a [self performSelector:@selector(doneMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];